# How do I use firebase firestore for my desktop app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the firebase-ui-android authentication flow for my mobile app.
I would like to do the same for my desktop app, but it doesn't seem like there is an equivalent framework; the closest seems to be firebase-ui-web.
Now I'm playing with the idea of (ab?)using firebase-ui-web to run locally on the client machine for authentication.
However, since firebase-ui-web seems to be aimed at the server I'm a bit wary running it on the client side.

The desktop app is fairly simple, it pretty much only needs to read some firestore data.

What are my options here?

Comment: What platform would the desktop app target? Also: what use-case will this desktop app cater to? Most developers target desktop users through their web app.

Comment: Primarily windows. The desktop app is a game that works in conjunction with the user's mobile device which shows additional information received from the desktop app via firebase cloud messaging. The mobile device essentially functions as a second screen for the game to show ingame stats. My main problem right now is somehow sending the phone device id over to the desktop app so I can start sending the notifications. I thought the best way to do this would be to authenticate users on the phone, write the device id to firestore and then read it on desktop.

Comment: For Firestore you could use the REST API. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api. But I'd highly recommend considering a web app, since there is an SDK for that.

Comment: If I use a web app then how do I pass the authentication token/firestore data from the browser back to my desktop app? Are there any firebase best practices for this?

Comment: If you're using a web app, there is no desktop app. Instead the user just signs into the web app from their desktop, and the web app uses the Firebase Authentication SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

Answer (score 2):

The only ways to connect with Firebase are by an Android, an iOS and a web app.

There is no support for desktop apps.

But, you can create a native sync service to link your desktop app with Firebase users throught a web service.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use firestore with desktop app using flutter, and I couldn't find any working solution.

I tried this and it worked:
on the firebase_option.dart file I change the code to this:

```
static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
if (kIsWeb) {
  return web;
}
switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
  case TargetPlatform.android:
    return android;
  case TargetPlatform.iOS:
    return ios;
  case TargetPlatform.macOS:
    return macos;
  case TargetPlatform.windows:
    return android;
  case TargetPlatform.linux:
    throw UnsupportedError(
      'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
      'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
    );
  default:
    throw UnsupportedError(
      'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
    );
}
```

}

And this for the main.dart file:

```
void main() async {
  Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

"I don't know if there will be any problem on this, I just wanted to use firebase with desktop. If there is anything new, I'll post it here"

Comment: Please **DO NOT** attach images of code. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to add your code as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible to have a desktop app to connect to Firebase. However you should create a hybrid desktop app using electron or other platforms that is by nature use web and javascript. Here is an example of using electron to manage firebase: https://www.electronjs.org/apps/firebase-admin

Comment: depends on security its preferred not to use firebase in electron of js/ts/ web codes with can be easily modified when sending any request to firebase. best and secure solution is to use a web service intermidate for firebase and desktop for security

Comment: Any request sent to Firebase database will be evaluated by rules you set on the data. If a user didn't satisfy the conditions you set then the request will be rejected. So we need to make sure our users are correctly authenticated. Using Firebase Admin SDK is not possible directly in web client applications (unless is done via localhost server) and that is the dangerous part of the SDK that should be kept out of client code. Anything else that uses Firebase Mobile/Web Client SDK is safe if you set the rules correctly. So in summary avoid using local servers and Admin SDK on desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Sign-In for TVs and Devices](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/devices?authuser=0) for that case.

This is not perfect, because you need to use additional access code, but it can work with desktop applications as well